# CodingBat Python warmup-2 array123, one line solution won't work

Tags: python, return, boolean-expression

The problem is this:

Given an array of ints, return True if the sequence of numbers 1, 2, 3 appears in the array somewhere.

Can be found here:

https://codingbat.com/prob/p193604

My iterative solution which works is this:

```
has_seq = False

for i in range(len(nums) - 2):
    if nums[i: i + 3] == [1, 2, 3]:  # do indexes i .. i + 3 equal 1, 2, 3
        has_seq = True
        break  # exit loop if condition met

return has_seq
```

I'm trying to turn it into a one line return, the code I have so far for that is this:

```
return bool(True for i in range(len(nums) - 2) if nums[i: i + 3] == [1, 2, 3])
```

This isn't working and always returns True even when test cases shows it shouldn't. What am I doing wrong? If it is not possible to do a one line return for this why?

Answer (score 0):

You're giving `bool` a generator object, and as far as I know, generators are always truthy.

You want [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) here instead of `bool`:

```
return any(nums[i: i + 3] == [1, 2, 3] for i in range(len(nums) - 2))
```

Comment: You don't need the `True for`.  The if condition can be moved to the beginning.
`any(nums[i:i + 3] == [1, 2, 3] for i in range(len(nums) - 2))`

Comment: Carcigenicate and @FrankYellin thanks for the help so far. I have tried your given solutions but it’s still not working. When I try compile I get the error of ‘any’ not being defined. Did this solution work on their website for you?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I try [to] compile"?  Are you using Python?  any() is a built in function.

Comment: @LogicallySpeakingLaura I can't think of how `any` would not be defined, unless they explicitly disallowed it for this challenge.

Comment: No I mean when try to submit the solution on their website, not a Python IDE. Maybe they just won’t accept it for some reason.